# center alignment varies from deskop to mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am using the following code to center my div and center the text in my div. This works perfect in my desktops browsers but is spaced bad on ipad and iphones.

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ps7t1rnu/

css

```
.center-box {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ccc;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.cb-text-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

html

```
<div class="center-box">
    <div class="cb-text-center"> FOOBAR
        BAR BAR
    </div>
</div>
```

The div is centered correctly (as visible on jsfiddle on browser - but on iPhone or iPad it move away from the screen with some weird spacing..

seem image:

[image: mobile screen shot]

You can see the issue when you look at the jsfiddle full screen result - https://jsfiddle.net/ps7t1rnu/embedded/result/ on browser and iPad/iPhone.

thanks for the help..

Comment: You have `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">` in your document's `<head>` section?

Comment: Also, Webkit-based browsers might need prefixing `transform`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS Safari until and including iOS 8.4, as well as Android browser up until and including Android 4.4 require prefixing the `transform` property.

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; width=device-width;">
```